# Mostrar UIViewController solo la primera vez que se abre la app

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo un problema, he implementado GCM en mi aplicación y he creado un UIViewController para que sea el inicial y en el que se realiza el registro necesario de este sistema.

Una vez realizado, salta un `UIAlertController` cuyo botón te lleva directamente a la página inicial de la aplicación a través de una `segue` manual. Hasta aquí no hay problema pero quiero saber como hacer para que a partir de entonces, se realice la `segue` directamente sin que se muestre este `ViewController`.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con GCM?

Comment: El sistema de notificaciones de Google: Google Cloud Messaging @mhergon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es un error de concepto. Es decir, haz que tu aplicación vaya directamente al `UIViewController` que aparecerá después del login, y presenta esta pantalla en el `viewWillAppear` del VC original. Luego, cuando salta el `UIAlertController` solo tienes que hacer un `dismiss` del VC de login.

Algo de este tipo debería funcionar:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if ((defaults.objectForKey("firstRun") == nil)) {
        defaults.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "firstRun")

        let loginVC = UIViewController()
        self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

En Objective C:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        UIViewController *loginVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
       [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: Me podrías guiar un poco, soy nuevo en esto... Gracias!

Comment: @JaviRando actualize mi respuesta. El código que he puesto debería de ir en el controlador al que accederás una vez completado el login.

Comment: Perfecto! Lo pruebo y te comento

Comment: Supongo que el Inicial debe ser en el que introduzco ese código

Comment: @JaviRando correcto y el loginVC tu pantalla de login.

Comment: No funciona, me salta un error en el loginVC en un `label` y no entiendo por qué

Comment: Puede que mi problema esté en que mi Controlador Inicial es uno creado para disponer de un menú lateral y el código lo estoy añadiendo a la primera pantalla visible como tal

Comment: @JaviRando El código has de ponerlo, si usas storyboard, en el controlador que este definido como initial view controller.

Comment: Pero ese, lo descargué como ejemplo para crear un menú lateral y está escrito en Objective-C

Comment: @JaviRando te pego el código en Objective C. Cambia el tag de la pregunta, que estaba puesto swift.

Comment: En qué parte del código iría? Nunca he utilizado este lenguaje